# Python - generate filename from supplied pattern

Tags: python, templates, generator, filenames

Before I get too far into making my own module, I wanted to ask if there is already something like this available.  I'm making an application that creates output files from input files, and I would like the ability to name the output file based on a configurable template.  For instance, the template might look like the following:

```
"Output_"<DATE:YYYYMMDD>"_"<DATE:HHMMSS>".txt"
```

to create files like `Output_20190606_130612.txt`

or it might look like:

```
<SEQUENCE:00-99>"-"<DATE:YYYYMMDD>".dat"
```

to create files like `13_20190606.dat`

Is there any module in Python that already has this functionality?

**EDIT:**
The template will be user-configurable, e.g. in a configuration file that the main application reads.  The template will be a combination of fixed strings and fields that will be populated by the application, but the application won't know ahead of time which fields will be used in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a template string like this

```
template = "Output_{YYYYMMDD}_{HHMMSS}.txt"
```

And then when saving the file format the string

```
file_name = template.format(YYYYMMDD="20190606", HHMMSS="130612")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The template will be user-configurable, e.g. in a configuration file that the main application reads.  The template will be a combination of fixed strings and fields that will be populated by the application.